# Вывести информацию о самой молодой, рослой и легкой команде

Tags: c++, классы, вывод

Я написала программу, только осталось вывести информацию о самой молодой, рослой и легкой команде. Буду очень признательна, если кто-нибудь поможет закончить программу...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class Competitor
{
char country[100];
char team[32];
char name[100];
int number;
int age[2];
int height[3];
int weight[3];  
public:
void fillData();
void showData();
};
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
system("chcp 1251");
int const N = 2;
Competitor obj[N];
cout << "Внесите данные об участниках спортивных соревнований" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    obj[i].fillData();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    obj[i].showData();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
void Competitor::fillData()
{
cout << "Страна: ";
cin.getline(country, 100);
cout << "Название команды: ";
cin.getline(team, 32);
cout << "Ф.И. игрока: ";
cin.getline(name, 100);
cout << "Игровой номер: ";
cin >> number;
cout << "Возраст игрока: ";
cin >> age[2];
cout << "Рост игрока: ";
cin >> height[3];
cout << "Вес игрока: ";
cin >> weight[3];
cin.get();
cout << endl;
}

void Competitor::showData()
{
// Здесь нужно вывести информацию о самой молодой (по возрасту), рослой (по росту) и легкой (по весу) команде.
cout << "Страна: " << country << " | Название команды: " << team << " | Ф.И. игрока: " << name << " | Игровой номер: " << number << " | Возраст: " << age << " | Рост: " << height << " | Вес: " << weight << endl;
}
```

Comment: мало того, что у вас команда состоит из одного игрока,  его возраст еще и имеет два значения, к  тому же вы  пытаетесь вводить и третий возраст  cin >> age[2]; Ту же ошибку совершаете и с другими массивами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как верно заметил [AR Hovsepyan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277611/ar-hovsepyan), в начале стоит поправить сам класс. А для решения проблемы помогут алгоритмы из STL библиотеки.

```
std::min_element();
std::max_element();
```

На примере поля age вашего класса:

```
std::min_element(age, age+sz); // sz - размер вашего массива. Стоит заметить, что функция вернет указатель на элемент
```

А вообще, я бы рекомендовал вам создать отдельный класс "участник", в котором будет информация об участнике (рост, вес и т.п.) и отдельно создать класс "команда", в котором будет информация о команде (массив объектов класса "участник" и информация о команде).

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую сделать так как Вы сказали